# MySQL: joining tables through a series of relations - reducing duplicate table reads

Tags: mysql, join

I'm reading an article about join in MySQL, but I don't understand why **Joining tables through a series of relations has the advantage of reducing duplicate table reads.**
Can someone explain with examples? Thanks.

Quoted text below:

> Stated visually, these two ways of joining tables looks like: 
>   Series of Relations: table 1 -> 2 -> 3
>   Common Relation: table 1 -> 2, (1) -> 3 
>   Either way, MySQL reads table 1, then 2, then 3—its "single-sweep
>   multi-join method." The "(1)" in the common relation join means that
>   when table 3 is read, rows in it are found using its relation to table
>   1, not table 2 as in the series of relations join. Joining tables
>   through a series of relations has the advantage of reducing duplicate
>   table reads if the first table is the most restrictive, the second
>   table less restrictive, the third table even less restrictive, etc.

Text from hackmysql.com/case5

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is simply referencing to the following two (unrealistic) examples, although I could be wrong.

*Note the way in which table 3 is joined in each.*

**Table 1 -> 2 -> 3**

```
    SELECT t1.name, t2.phoneNo, t3.address
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2
         ON t2.id = t1.id
    JOIN table3 t3
         ON t3.id = t2.id
    WHERE t1.id = 123
```

**Table 1 -> 2, (1) -> 3**

```
    SELECT t1.name, t2.phoneNo, t3.address
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2
         ON t2.id = t1.id
    JOIN table3 t3
         ON t3.id = t1.id
    WHERE t1.id = 123
```

Regards,
Chris

Comment: uhm I understood about that, but still didn't figure out why one has the advantage of reducing duplicate table reads, and the other doesn't.

Comment: I assume that in the first example, table2 is read twice.  First in the JOIN on table1, and second in the JOIN on table3.